# How to output Polygon with latitude and longitude set in EntityValue function?

Tags: geography, entity

I used `EntityValue` to represent a map of a country.

```
 EntityValue[Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], "Polygon"] /.  g_GeoPosition :> g["LongitudeLatitude"]
```

As a result of the above execution, the bounds are `{{126,130},{33.2, 38.6}}`. I want to adjust this range to `{{126,130},{34.2, 38.6}}` to get a `Polygon`. Any good way?

In fact, I want to remove the island at the bottom of the map of this country. So I want to get polygons for the map body of this country.

Comment: All three tags on this question were new. Please try to avoid creating entirely new tag names unless really necessary. Try to use existing tags when possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First,

```
Graphics[EntityValue[Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], "Polygon"] /.  
  g_GeoPosition :> g["LongitudeLatitude"], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Second,

```
Graphics[EntityValue[Entity["Country", "SouthKorea"], "Polygon"] /.  
g_GeoPosition :> g["LongitudeLatitude"],PlotRange -> {{126, 129.5}, {34, 39}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Exactly the result I wanted.

Comment: @user21427. Since this answer is what you wanted, I suggest you accept it